# ion-long-press conflicts with click event

Tags: css, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have list of messages that generated using ngFor loop, each one has a long press even that uses the  module, now when the user long presses the div it runs an event that passes the div-id and turns true a variable that enables highlight on div if it's id matches, basically each div has ngClass binding matching it's id with stored id, when a user long presses I move pressed div's id to the variable so the test becomes true for that div,

The issue is with turning off the highlight when
-User clicks outside the div
-Taps the div again once it's selected

In programming I simple need to set my variable where I am moving the id to null, but where to write code to achieve that is trouble

here is the div list

```html
<div class="message" *ngFor="let l of list" [ngClass]="{'selected':isMessageSelected(l)}" [class.left]="l.sender != me"
      [class.right]="l.sender == me" ion-long-press [interval]="400" (onPressStart)="pressed()" (onPressing)="active($event,l)"
      (onPressEnd)="released()">
```

The code for three events that are run each time a div if long pressed

```js
pressed() {
    this.logger.info('Pressed');
    this.logger.info('@Pressed', this.l);
  }

  active(event: Event, l) {
    this.editModeActive = true;
    this.msg = l;
    this.selectedMessage = l.uid;
  }

  released() {
    this.logger.info('Released');
  }
```

Putting a click event on the div instantly runs it when long press is triggered, so checking the editModeActive doesn't help either.

Note: putting a click event on whole body also triggers it when a div is long pressed,

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this?

Link to the ion long press npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-long-press